# RegExp constructor in a switch statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have some regex patterns in an object literal which I would like to `switch` over when I look for certain patters like security numbers.

Why do I get a match on `abc` below?

Simplified version of my code:

```
var cst = {
    SECURITYNUMBER: /^\d{12}$/
};

function doStuff(query){

    $.each(query.split(' '), function(i, word){

        switch(true){
            case new RegExp(cst.SECIRUTYNUMBER).test(word): 
                console.log('match');
                break;
        }

    });
}

doStuff('198610054937 abc');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t1ps0vdh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a typo... instead of using `SECURITYNUMBER`, you've used `SECIRUTYNUMBER`.

Change...

```
case new RegExp(cst.SECIRUTYNUMBER).test(word):
```

To...

```
case new RegExp(cst.SECURITYNUMBER).test(word):
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t1ps0vdh/1/

Comment: I know the feeling @Johan, just needed a 2nd pair of eyes